# yii2 Access control is not working

Tags: php, yii2

This is my code. without login also i can enter into the home page. when press on logout button its takes me to the login page. if i load again the home page without login it works. how i resolve this issue?

```
 public function behaviors()
        {
            return [
                'access' => [
                    'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                    'only' => ['logout','index','prospects','merchants','accounts','notifications','reports','view-prospect','new-merchant-account-info','new-merchant-bank-info','new-merchant-business-info','new-merchant-success-message','new-merchant','new-prospect-success-message','edit-prospect','new-prospect'],
                    'rules' => [
                         [
                            'allow' => true,
                            'actions' => [],
                            'roles' => ['?'],
                        ],
                        [
                            'actions' => ['logout','index','prospects','merchants','accounts','notifications','reports','view-prospect','new-merchant-account-info','new-merchant-bank-info','new-merchant-business-info','new-merchant-success-message','new-merchant','new-prospect-success-message','edit-prospect','new-prospect'],
                            'allow' => true,
                            'roles' => ['@'],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'verbs' => [
                    'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                    'actions' => [
                        'logout' => ['post'],
                    ],
                ],
            ];
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read this :
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html

> `actions`: specifies which actions this rule matches. This should be an array of action IDs. The comparison is case-sensitive. **If this option is empty or not set, it means the rule applies to all actions**.

So you should simply try :

```
'rules' => [
    [
        'actions' => ['login'],
        'allow' => true,
        'roles' => ['?'],
    ],
    [
        'actions' => ['logout','index','prospects','merchants','accounts','notifications','reports','view-prospect','new-merchant-account-info','new-merchant-bank-info','new-merchant-business-info','new-merchant-success-message','new-merchant','new-prospect-success-message','edit-prospect','new-prospect'],
        'allow' => true,
        'roles' => ['@'],
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should restrict the access to guest only to the login page

```
  public function behaviors()
      {
          return [
              'access' => [
                  'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                  'only' => ['login',],
                  'rules' => [
                       [
                          'allow' => true,
                          'actions' => [],
                          'roles' => ['?'],
                      ],
                      [
                          'actions' => ['logout','index','prospects','merchants','accounts','notifications','reports','view-prospect','new-merchant-account-info','new-merchant-bank-info','new-merchant-business-info','new-merchant-success-message','new-merchant','new-prospect-success-message','edit-prospect','new-prospect'],
                          'allow' => true,
                          'roles' => ['@'],
                      ],
                  ],
              ],
              'verbs' => [
                  'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                  'actions' => [
                      'logout' => ['post'],
                  ],
              ],
          ];
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can set login url will access everyone.

roles => ['?']

and logout action will access only login user

roles => ['@']

Rest all the action you can add in this function

```
 'rules' => [
        [
            'actions' => ['login'],
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['?'],
        ],
        [
            'actions' => ['logout'],
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['@'],
        ],
    ],
```